# How i can get the latest due date with Linq

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

the problem has been fixed. Re-edit for the correct answer.

I had problem with Linq. How to get the due date from db. There are three tables in database involved. They are table Accounts, Transactions, System Invoices. As i have account number input, it will get the results linked with three tables.

one account have many transactions and systeminvoices.

tblAccounts.id = tbltransactions.Accountid,  tbltransactions.id = tblsysteminvoices.id

I am trying to find the latest DueDate in the system invoices and display that due date. I need help to check the linq that i wrote if its wrong. The result i got is null when i debug. Here is the linq i wrote in controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string useracc = (string)Session["AccountNumber"];
    var accountInstance = db.Accounts.FirstOrDefault(w => w.AccountNumber.ToString() == useracc);
    List<Transaction> AccountTransactions = db.Transactions.Where(w => w.AccountId == accountInstance.Id&&w.IsCancelled ==false).Select(w => w).OrderByDescending(w => w.Date).ToList();
    var accountStatement = AccountTransactions.Where(w =>  w.TransactionTypeId == 2 && w.Date.Year >= 2015).OrderByDescending(w => w.Date).ToList();
    var lastTransactionId = db.Transactions.Where(w => w.AccountId == accountInstance.Id && w.IsCancelled == false && w.TransactionTypeId == 2 && w.Date.Year >= 2015).Max(t => t.Id);
    var needDueDate = db.SystemInvoices.Where(s => s.Id == lastTransactionId).Select(s => s.DueDate).FirstOrDefault();

    var credits = AccountTransactions.Where(w => w.Type.ToString().Contains("CREDIT")).Sum(w => w.Amount);
    var debits = AccountTransactions.Where(w => w.Type.ToString().Contains("DEBIT")).Sum(w => w.Amount+w.Tax);

    List<customBalanceInfoItem> currCustomBalance = new List<customBalanceInfoItem>();

    customBalanceInfoItem displayItem = new customBalanceInfoItem();
    displayItem.Balance = debits-credits;
    displayItem.AccountNumber = accountInstance.AccountNumber;

    currCustomBalance.Add(displayItem);
    return View(currCustomBalance); 
}

public partial class Account
{
    public Account()
    {
        this.Transactions = new HashSet<Transaction>();
    }   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string AccountName { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }        
}

public partial class Transaction
{
    public Transaction()
    {

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public bool IsCancelled { get; set; }    
    public virtual Account Account { get; set; }
    public virtual SystemInvoice SystemInvoice { get; set; }

}

public partial class SystemInvoice
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDue { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalDueIncTax { get; set; }    
    public virtual Transaction Transaction { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you think you could post your object model?

Answer (score 0):

This line looks confusing

```
     var systemInvoice = db.SystemInvoices.Where(w => w.Id == accountStatement.OrderByDescending(s => s.Id).Select(s => s.Id).FirstOrDefault()).Select(w=> w);
```

I guess you want find the invoice with the latest transaction. Check the following out.

```
    string useracc = (string)Session["AccountNumber"];
    var accountInstance = db.Accounts
                          .FirstOrDefault(w => w.AccountNumber.ToString() == useracc);
    if (accountInstance == null) {
        return
    };
    var lastTransactionId = db
                              .Transactions
                              .Where(w => w.AccountId == accountInstance.Id&&w.IsCancelled ==false);
                              .Where(w => w.TransactionTypeId == 2 && w.Date.Year >= 2015)
                              .Max(t => t.Id)
                              ;

     var needDuedate = db.SystemInvoices
                         .Where(inv =>  lastTransactionId == inv.Id)
                         .OrderByDescending(inv => Inv.DueDate)
                         .select(inv => inv.DueDate)
                         .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but when i debug with var needDuedate, i got Date = {1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM}, also got error msg :"Unable to create a constant value of type 'Portal.Models.Transaction'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context." , any idea with this?

Comment: do you mean to get the due date of invoice that has ID equals to the largest transaction ID?

Comment: yes, one transactionid = one invoiceid, i tried solution above  and still get Date = {1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM} from var needDueDate

Comment: Hmmm, do you get a valid lastTransactionId? if yes, can you query the database to see if the invoice has a valid DueDate?

Comment: yes, i checked db, id= 134163, dueDate =2016-02-11 00:00:00.000 ,but i want to only display dd/MM/yyyy. as i got return duedate, got Date = {1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM}

Comment: sorry i have no idea how to fix it. TT. Do i need change DueDate datatype? from datetime to string?

Comment: Finally , i worked out why the DueDate cannot display correctly, i will re-edit my post. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Transaction> AccountTransactions = db.Transactions.Include("SystemInvoice")
.Where(w => w.AccountId == accountInstance.Id&&w.IsCancelled ==false).OrderByDescending(w => w.Date).ToList(); 
    var needDuedate = AccountTransactions.Max(at=>at.SystemInvoice.DueDate);
```

Will this help?

Comment: yes, it can filter out the result, but debug with needDueDate, got Date = {1/01/0001 12:00:00 AM}